# Basic encryption/ openssl basic questions. DES CTR mode and misc

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, cygwin, des

I'm going to make this quick and dirty as my first question drew complaints that it was too long. I'm working on a cryptography assignment and I'm having a little trouble with it. I'll post the question then outline the specific area I'm having issues with. Hopefully I may garner a little mroe information that way.

## Assignment question

1. Either download openssl to encrypt a message using DES, or download a python script to perform the encryption and
   decryption.
   5
   (a) Encrypte the phrase:

In the spring of 1861, decades of simmering tensions between the northern and southern United States
over issues including states’ rights versus federal authority, westward expansion and slavery exploded
into the American Civil War (1861-65).

Use DES with the following information: CTR mode; no salt, no IV, with the key, in hex, of the last 64 bits of
the SHA-1 hash of your student ID. Include appropriate screen shots and other evidence to convince me you have
done the encryption.

(b) Verify the "complementation property"
1
of DES. For the message, use the 64 bits, in hex: 2df87ac380f2f4c1. Use
the same key as in the previous part.

## My question

Okay SO! I'm not asking for you guys to do my question (although if you want to throw some good directions for me to head I'm totally up for that.

What I do need is clarification on a couple of things.

First of all, I installed openssl with Cygwin and upon trying to encipher the file I hit a number of hitches that completely threw me in regards to the question.

1. For some reason I have no idea where to put a plaintext file so Cygwin can path directly to it. Trying to use the whole path of the .txt seems to yield errors. So where would I put the plaintext into openssl/cygwin to read directly? (i.e where is it's "root")

(trying a generic encryption command yields an error

"aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc
secrets.txt: No such file or directory
2674688:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('secrets.txt','rb')
2674688:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
error in aes-256-cbc
")

1. Cygwin openssl doesn't seem to come with CTR mode, and CTR mode definitely requires an IV so I presume my professor wants me to do it with all of these options. Do I have to import or otherwise acquire the CTR cipher?

Any other tips on where to get started on this question would be fantastic.

I can't post many URLs but I do want to demonstrate I have done at least some research so I've compiled the lsit of links in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/GDhq7GmQ

Anyways I suck at this subject but I do want to do very well, so any inroads you guys can give me would be very appreciated.

Humbly yours,
a slowly failing ITSec firstyear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to use the SSL as a library, not as a CLI tool. CTR is not hard to create using "raw" block encryption. There is a encryption mode that is more or less "raw" block encryption.

It's a bit strange that you need to use the last bytes of the SHA-1 hash as a key, normally the first (leftmost) bytes are used.

Comment: Hmmm I've read in quite a few of the sources that you can use it for basic encrypt/decrypt. But the problem I'm having is actually just finding out where I should/can dump .txt files for it to read. If I could at least get it to have a look at a file I could move forward, but as it stands I'm left scratching my head. I could try and find a python script to do it but that might involve starting from scratch & time is of the essence. Also I'd like to develop some knowledge of this tool. But maybe I'm doing this wrong?

Comment: Using C and link to openssl, there should be a few samples around to do this. What you are trying to do is basically byte handling - it's not a good idea to do this using shell scripting.

Comment: Yeah, well I figured out how to get it to input and output to disk, just by placing the .txts on the root drive. Feel a bit stupid. However the second part trying to encode with DES CTR mode is puzzling.

Comment: Byte handling? This is homework though, we're doing stuff I imagine you wouldn't do in the field e.g computing xor hashes by hand ;(